# Trying to parse JSON data in iOS

Tags: ios, json

here is my code and JSON result I get in my app.

```
NSArray* logindata = [json objectForKey:@"logindata"]; //2
NSLog(@"logindata: %@", logindata); //3
```

And the logindata Array comes through as this:

```
 logindata: {
    code = 200;
    goodLogin = 1;
}
```

How would I get the value of goodLogin?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked and tried this before asking for help? http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 Just saying that a little effort sometimes helps. ;-)

Comment: I've been following that page and I just can't seem to work it out because their JSON url contains lots of info, whereas mine contains just two values..

Comment: It's just a bunch of NSDictionary. Use objectAtIndex:0 and objectForKey:@"code" and you should be set.

Comment: You would search here and elsewhere on the web for info on JSON parsing, or simply go to the Apple doc page for [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and go from there.

Comment: (But, of course, you need to understand Objective-C first, which would imply understanding what an NSDictionary is.)

Answer (score 1):

The loginData you posted isn't actual JSON (unless there is some other way to display it that I don't know), but from what I understand of your example, your call to

```
[json objectForKey:@"logindata"];
```

should return a NSDictionary, not a NSArray.

So, something more like

```
NSDictionary *logindata = [json objectForKey:@"logindata"];
NSNumber *goodLogin = [loginData objectForKey:"goodLogin"]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @David that worked. I've got a lot of reading up to do!

Answer (score -1):

Based on the output, it looks like `logindata` is an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSArray`.

If you cast it correctly, you can get the value:

```
NSDictionary *logindata = [json objectForKey:@"logindata"];
NSNumber *goodLogin = [logindata objectForKey:@"goodLogin"];

// goodLogin.intValue == 1
```